# Template specification problem

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do the folllowing:
class definition h file:

```
template<int Size>
class Sculptor
{
public:
    Sculptor();

    ~Sculptor(void) ;

    void Sculp(SculptData* sculpData);

    void ToShape(Shape* shape);

    int CalculateMesh();

    unsigned char sculpture[Size][Size][Size];
}
```

class definition cpp file to shape function (all others are the same):

```
template<int Size>
void Sculptor<Size>::ToShape(Shape* shape){}
```

usage:

```
    Sculptor<16> sclupt;

Shape shape;

SculptData* data = CreateCircle();


sclupt.Sculp(data);
sclupt.CalculateMesh();
sclupt.ToShape(&shape);
```

and I get the following error 
[image]

Could you please show me the source of the problem ?

Comment: Is it a case of: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13 ?

Comment: Edited added example from cpp file

Comment: Exactly - it's in a different cpp file presumably, so never gets instantiated in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the implementation of a template class must be visible from the compilation unit that uses it. In particular, you may not place the implementation into a separate .cpp file (as is common practice with non-template classes) but instead should place it in the header file where the template was declared.

Comment: @Sergey Kucher: Yes. Class templates do not compile down to actual machine code because the types are not known yet.

Answer (score 3):

99% of the time a `LNK2019` means that you forgot to actually fully define the body of a function or a class that you've used somewhere. <strike>Where's the implementation for `ToShape()`, `Sculp()`, and `CalculateMesh()`? What about the constructor and the destructor</strike>?

It appears that you are putting the implementations into a `.cpp` file. While it is understandable that one should separate the interface from the implementation, class templates are completely different beasts from non-templates.

The compiler doesn't actually generate any machine code for templates because not all the template parameters have been defined yet. You can't generate the machine code for `Sculptor` without knowing how big the member array is going to be, for example. The compiler doesn't know in advance that `Size == 16` when the compiler comes to parsing the template definition. So you get linker errors since the linker can't find the machine code for it; it doesn't exist!

For template classes you would typically put the implementation in the template class declaration itself<strike>, so you're probably really are missing those function definitions</strike> like this:

```
template<int Size> 
class Sculptor 
{ 
public: 
    Sculptor()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    // and so on...
```

The templates in the Boost libraries and the C++ Standard Library are defined like this.

---

A side note: with `Size == 16`, you're creating a 3x3 array with 4096 `unsigned char`s in it. While that's not a problem in of itself, it's quite easy to overflow the stack when a single `Sculptor` occupies at least 4096 `unsigned char`s on the stack.

Comment: That's most likely your problem then. In general template function need to visible to the code that uses them (the full definition and not just the declaration). That usually means you have to put the body of the template functions in a .h file and include them everythere they are neded

Comment: about your Side note What is my upper bound? actually when size is 1024 I get stack overflow

Comment: @Sergey Kucher: That depends on how much stack space the operating system allocates to you. While a single `Sculptor` may not overflow, you may allocate multiple `Sculptors`. Again, it's not a problem per se, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you,I will make my sculptor is singleton

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write the code for ToShape, Sculp, CalculateMesh, constructor and destructor. Implement them or add a dummy implementation and the program will link.

Also:

```
unsigned char array sculpture[Size][Size][Size];
```

is not valid C++ (unless array is some void define), did you mean this instead?

```
unsigned char sculpture[Size][Size][Size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates must be fully defined in all translation units in which they are used- you can't link them in. This means that the compiler cannot find the body of the functions you are calling.